# How to Convert Object to array in Angular 4?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I want to convert my `Object` to array, here is my Object.

```
{5.0: 10, 28.0: 14, 3.0: 6}
```

I want array like below

```
[{"type": 5.0,"value":10},{"type": 28.0,"value":14}, {"type": 3.0,"value":6}]
```

or

```
[{"5.0": 10},{"28.0": 14}, {"3.0": 6}]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Get the keys via `Object.keys` and then use `map` function to get the desired output.

```js
const obj = {5.0: 10, 28.0: 14, 3.0: 6};

const mapped = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({type: key, value: obj[key]}));

console.log(mapped);
```

Another solution can be provided via `Object.entries` and *array destructuring*.

```js
const obj = {5.0: 10, 28.0: 14, 3.0: 6};

const mapped = Object.entries(obj).map(([type, value]) => ({type, value}));

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: in your second approach when returning value is  'auto creating key -value ' is about destructuring too?

Comment: Destructuring part is going only in the parameters - `([type, value])`. I get an array in the parameters and destruct them into single parameters instead of doing `param[0]` and `param[1]`

Comment: and how about this part `({type, value})`? you are supplying only values and returned array has keys too

Comment: Yes, when you just pass the property, it creates a key with the same name. In this case I have an object with two properties - `type` and `value`. This `{type, value}` is equivalent to `{type: type, value: value}`

Answer (score 11):

Use Object.keys and array.map:

```js
var obj = {5.0: 10, 28.0: 14, 3.0: 6}

var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({type: key, value: obj[key]}));

console.log(arr);
```

And if your browser supports Object.entries, you can use it:

```js
var obj = {5.0: 10, 28.0: 14, 3.0: 6}

var arr = Object.entries(obj).map(([type, value]) => ({type, value}));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Same answer no duplicate answer please

Comment: @AvanishKumar  don't have intention to duplicate someone's answer, I answered at the time he answered