# How to force Object type returned from an Observable to an array of objects in Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, observable

I'm obtaining a response using GET like this.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

items: Item[];
stuff: any[];

ngOnInit() {
  const url = ...;
  this.http.get(url)
    .subscribe(next => {
      console.log(next);
      console.log(next.length);
      this.items = next;
      this.stuff = next;
    });
}
```

I can see that there's 6 elements and what they are (checking the console). However, neither of the fields seem to the the array. I'm trying to iterate out the elements using the *ngFor* directive but seeing nothing or just a single line.

```
<div ngFor="let item of items">
  ->{{item?.id}}
</div>

<div ngFor="let item of stuff">
  ->{{item?.id}} 
</div>
```

I know that I can resolve it by exposing the data through a service [like this](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/) but partly, I want to do a quicky here and learn how to do it; partly, I'm going to have the very same problem in the service code instead.

I've tried using *map* and *forEach* on the *next* value but I got the error saying that *Object* isn't an *array*. The IDE suggested adding the work array to the syntax so it becomes *next.array.forEach* but that didn't even got executed, producing a lot of red ink.

What should I do? (Not sure what to google for at this stage.)

Comment: can you provide structure of `next` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
donkeyObservArray: Observable<Donkey[]>;
donkeyArray: Array<Donkey>;

this.donkeyObservArray.subscribe(donk=> {
this.donkeyArray = donk;

console.log(this.donkeyArray);
```

and to be happy...

Or get typed:

```
donkey: Donkey= null;

getDonkey(): Donkey{
    this.donkey = new Donkey();

this._http.get<Donkey>(...your ws link)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.donkey = data;
```

Comment: Yeah, it was **this** that I was looking for. I'm used to the typing syntax in C# but in JS, it still feels... too fancy. Thanks. Also - I had another error, which was the missing star character in the *ngFor*. Luckily, I saw it, finally.

Answer (score 1):

You can either convert the object to an array before passing to template 
[object-2-array-angular-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271065/how-to-convert-object-to-array-in-angular-4)

or use a custom pipe to transform object to array