# Best way to read objects data in realtime databse to convert it to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read the data that i have in the realtime firebase, but when i read it, the data comes with objects inside the array, so i cant use *ngFor to access the data like i am use to.

I have this data in the realtime database:

```
waiting 
   |
   ---------olaaaa 
   |          |
   |          ----------test1
   |         
   ---------olaaaaa2
   |          |
   |         -----------test2
```

when i read the data, the array comes like this :

```
{ olaaaa: {}, olaaaa2: {} }
```

and i don't want that, i want the array to come without the names olaaa and olaaa2. Like this:

```
{{test},{test2}}
```

To read i use this:

```
this.af.object("/waiting").query.once('value')
```

How can i get the info like arrays and not objects?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with firebase, but what I have read you could add a `.then()` to your call and format your data using `Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key])` which I found from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49271095/8947748)

```
let res = [];
this.af.object("/waiting").query.once('value')
    .then(data => {
        res = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]);
     });
```